# Why are the Luma Thema sample images from Magento2 sample data not visible when extending it to a custom theme?

Tags: magento2, sample-data, custom-theme

I installed the Magento2 open source sample data and everything works fine. When I switch to the luma theme in the admin backend I can see everything. But when I create a custom theme based on luma theme the data/images is not visible anymore. What am I doing wrong? Should it be marked somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to make two sql queries in the database because it was a problem with the widgets assigned to the old theme:

UPDATE `layout_link` SET `theme_id` = '[CUSTOM_THEME_ID]'
UPDATE `widget_instance` SET `theme_id` = '[CUSTOM_THEME_ID]'