# Extending Magento 2 Luma theme missing images on home page

Tags: magento, magento2

I installed Magento 2.3 with sample data [on a GCE VM]. Then I created a custom theme, extending the default Luma theme, as described in the [official docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) and [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91930/how-to-extend-the-luma-theme).

However, when I switch over from Luma to my custom theme [via the admin panel], the images don't appear, even after I clear the cache.

Here's a visual:

**With Luma Theme**

[image]

**With My Custom Theme**

[image]

What do I need to tweak to get those images to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Looks like the last step requires a database operation as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820045/why-are-the-luma-thema-sample-images-from-magento2-sample-data-not-visible-when?rq=1).

Here are the steps:

1. Login to your mysql database

   `sudo mysql -u root -p`

   Enter your password when prompted.
2. Get your custom theme_id

   `SELECT theme_id from theme WHERE theme_path='[CUSTOM_THEME_PATH]'`;

   where `CUSTOM_THEME_PATH` is the name of your custom theme as defined in your composer.json file.
3. Update the *layout_link* table [with the id from step 2]

   `UPDATE layout_link SET theme_id = '[CUSTOM_THEME_ID]'`
4. Update the widget_instance table [with the id from step 2]

   `UPDATE widget_instance SET theme_id = '[CUSTOM_THEME_ID]'`
5. Clear the cache

Refresh the page, and the images should now appear.